# Handling Custom Event in Class from Form

Tags: c#, winforms, events, websocket

I am having problems attempting to handle an event I have created.  I am attempting to use WebSockets, and when I receive a message, I want to raise an event that one of my forms can subscribe to.

In my Form_Load Event. I have:

```
taskRoutingServer = new Core.WebSocketServerWrapper();
taskRoutingServer.MessageReceivedEvent += 
TaskRoutingServer_MessageReceivedEvent1;
```

The method in my form looks like:

```
private void TaskRoutingServer_MessageReceivedEvent1(object sender, WebSocketSharp.MessageEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I intend to handle and work with 'e' which will contain the data that my form needs to work with.  The WebSocket class I have looks like this:

```
public class WebSocketServerWrapper : WebSocketBehavior
{
  private WebSocketServer socketServer;
  public delegate void MessageReceivedEventHandler(object sender, MessageEventArgs e);
  public event MessageReceivedEventHandler MessageReceivedEvent;
  public string creator;

  public WebSocketServerWrapper()
  {
      socketServer = new WebSocketServer("ws://localhost:9001");
      socketServer.AddWebSocketService<WebSocketServerWrapper>("/ws");
  }

  public bool IsListening()
  {
      return socketServer.IsListening;
  }

  public void StartListening()
  {
      socketServer.Start();
  }

  public void StopListening()
  {
      socketServer.Stop();
  }

  protected override void OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
  {
      //invoke event
      MessageReceivedEvent?.Invoke(this, e);
  }
}
```

The behavior currently is that `OnMessage` fires but `MessageReceivedEvent` is null, so the event is not invoked.  How should I handle this event correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MessageReceivedEvent should not be null at this point:

```
MessageReceivedEvent?.Invoke(this, e);
```

when you've added a listener to it, which you wrote you did in OnLoad:

```
taskRoutingServer.MessageReceivedEvent += TaskRoutingServer_MessageReceivedEvent1;
```

This probably means that you are either

1. not firing the event on the same instance (the taskRoutingMessage object in onLoad), or
2. you've removed the listener at some point.

If "WebSocketBehaviour" is somehow being automatically created by the framework it will not be the same instance. Then you could try to use a static eventhandler:

```
    public static event MessageReceivedEventHandler MessageReceivedEvent;

    protected override void OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageReceivedEvent?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
```

...and set it like this in load:

```
Core.WebSocketServerWrapper.MessageReceivedEvent += 
                              TaskRoutingServer_MessageReceivedEvent1;
```

Comment: It appears to be related to #1 somehow in that in my form load, if I set a property, the property becomes null when the OnMessage fires... but I dont create a new instance anywhere else in my form.

Comment: Not used this WebSocketBehavior before, but could it be that it is automatically instantiated by the websocket framework?

Comment: If so, you could test by making the event static. I can update my answer to show an example as it is more convenient to write code there.

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed the case.  Making that event static resolved the issue.

Comment: Great, happy to help. One final note of caution is that you probably want to de-register the listener when closing the dialog. This depends on your implementation of course, but if the event-raiser continues to live beyond the scope of the form it might otherwise call the eventlistener on the disposed form.